# How could I pipe both stderr and stdout to the same file, coloring stderr red but not stdout?

Tags: bash, io

- I need to capture the output and errors of script.sh in
  a single log file, retaining the order in which the output and errors
  were written
- I need the errors to be colored red, so that they stand out.
- This needs to be done without modifying the contents of script.sh.

If script.sh executes the following:

```
echo "This is STDOUT line 1"
echo "This is STDERR line 2" >&2
echo "This is STDOUT line 3"
```

The log should look like

```
This is STDOUT line 1
[RED]This is STDERR line 2
This is STDOUT line 3
```

I know how to colorize text, so you may emit that explanation from your answer if you wish.

Thanks.

Comment: I searched for `[bash] color stderr` and that question came up first. What did you search for before posting?

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I had been searching for "color stderr but not stdout" and was looking for questions that had the 'not stderr' qualification. I'll look into the post you mentioned.